# Importing shapefile to SQL database, attributes are all NULL

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, mysql

I used ogr2ogr to import a shapefile into a MySQL database using the following:

```
ogr2ogr MYSQL:"db,host=localhost,user=root" -nln "map" -a_srs "EPSG:4683" map.shp -overwrite -addfields -fieldTypeToString All
```

but when I checked the table, all the attributes said "NULL" instead of their original values. What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried something similar with a random shapefile using MySQL 5.5, and got an error message saying that spatial indexes were not supported by my table type. A Google search found [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379808/the-used-table-type-doesnt-support-spatial-indexes), which made me think I'd have to use the ISAM engine option. I added "-lco ENGINE=MYISAM" to the end of my command and it worked. Your command might look like:

```
ogr2ogr -f "MySQL" MYSQL:"db,host=localhost,user=root" -nln "map" -a_srs "EPSG:4683" map.shp -overwrite -addfields -fieldTypeToString All -lco ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Comment: Hmm, my table was actually already using MyISAM. But I entered this and it actually worked! So thank you :)

Comment: No problem! I'm not really sure, but ogr2ogr (with the --overwrite option) may be deleting your old table and replacing it. If so, the need to call out the engine would make more sense. If you like my answer, could you mark it as the accepted answer?